# Changing Visible Field Properties on Multiple Layers at once in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes

I am new to using ArcGIS 10.0.

I have a map with a layer dealing with electrical primary circuits, that I split into multiple layers based on their unique circuit value.

Is there a way of changing which fields I want visible for **all my layers** at once?

Since I split the initial Primary Circuit layer, I now have about 120 layers to work with.

I tried changing the visibility of the fields in the initial Primary Circuit layer, but when the layer was split into all of the individual circuit layers, all of the fields turned back on.

Comment: This GeoNet thread may help https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85543 and also
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/85312#post349972

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your 120 layers are all in the same map and that having been "split" from the same original layer they will all have the same field names.

To turn the same field(s) off in all layers I would write a Python/ArcPy script that:

1. Creates a list object of the field name(s) you want to make invisible
2. Iterates through all your layers (arcpy.mapping.ListLayers)
3. Describes each layer to create a field info object
4. Uses the count property of the field info object to iterate through all the fields by their index number
5. Checks the name of each field iterated against the list from 1. and if it is found sets the setVisible property to False

There is a code sample in the [FieldInfo (arcpy) help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000074000000) which should put you well on the way to doing this.